# Local video is not working on Samsung smart TV Emulator

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I am developping a SAMSUNG SMart TV application to read a video from à local web server (Apache) following this tuto (tut00055)

But the window screen on the application remains black!

Here is a screen shot of my www folder:

http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=516795folder.png

and here is the project that I tested:

http://www74.zippyshare.com/v/54021535/file.html

I have also changed the folder permission, but in vain... the screen remains black!

I can read the videos with my browser (with the same URL!) but not with the Samsung Smart TV  emulator :(

And in the output console, I got always :

---

1060  Key pressed: 71

1061  PLAY

1062  Play

---

What's wrong with my application?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your videoList.xml don't use
    `<link>http://127.0.0.1/testy/alphabet.mp4</link>`

Rather your pc Apache IP address:
    `<link>http://192.168.32.138/testy/alphabet.mp4</link>`

192.168.32.138 is an example. In terminal type `ifconfig`, it will be the `inet addr` the Apache IP address you should use in the link tags.